# No access to USB port, when running python script on boot

Tags: python, usb, boot

I have a python script running with an RFID reader. The script runs fine when ran from terminal. When I add python `/home/pi/script.py &` to `/etc/profile` and reboot the Raspberry Pi, the scripts launches fine but gets stuck in this except:

```
while True:
#Setting up the RFID reader
    try:
        reader = mercury.Reader("tmr:///dev/ttyUSB0")

        break
    except TypeError:
        print('Error, manual reset. Retrying')
```

Why can't I access the USB port when running the python script on boot in /etc/profile?

## EDIT

1. attempt to fix the issue.
   Instead of adding it to `/etc/profile`, add it to `/etc/rc.local`. The script won't run when doing this.

## EDIT

I needed to `sudo raspi-config` and set the RPi to auto boot in desktop mode logged in as user pi. It now works!

Comment: the `/dev/ttyUSB0` does not exist at the time when you run your code ... run the code later in the boot sequesnce

Comment: Review:  I'd like to see more of the Python code, starting from the shebang and including the import(s).  Also, perhaps information about the Mercury wrapper ( https://github.com/gotthardp/python-mercuryapi ) and why it is being used instead of serial.   In the end, I see an answer in comments that is probably correct.  If the port does not yet exist then there would be no way to open it.  However, if that is really the answer then it would be best posted as such, with instructions about how to "run the code later in the boot sequence."

Comment: @SDsolar, i have no idea, off the top of my head, how to run the code later in the sequence. i only have a general idea of how linux behaves during the boot process ....... lol, i see that i misspelled sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jsotola adviced, you could run it later in the boot process.... or you can write your script to keep on trying to open the port over and over again till it's available (with a certain delay of a few seconds between attempts so that you don't go into a **tight loop**).

Addendum:
Apparently the tip that was followed was to start the script from rc.local... this is my full comment, just in case:

> Another would be to add it to /etc/rc.local which is run at the end of the boot sequence, if I'm not mistaken. Just make sure that the process actually goes in the background so that the script doesn't hang (run it with &, for example). There might be other details to take care but it should take care of running it veery late on the boot process.

Hope that's good enough to anyone looking for an answer later on.

Comment: How would you run it later in the boot process?

Comment: One way would be to add it to systemd (which has already been adviced). Another would be to add it to /etc/rc.local which is run at the end of the boot sequence, if I'm not mistaken. Just make sure that the process actually goes in the background so that the script doesn't hang (run it with &, for example). There might be other details to take care but it should take care of running it veery late on the boot process. But the simplest thing is just to make your script attempt to open the port every so often (say, every second.... or every 2 or 5 seconds) until it does open.

Comment: The information you placed in the comment about /etc/rc.local should be added to this answer. This solved the problem, and I therefore accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no relation between /etc/profile and the boot process. Add your script to the init process.

Comment: Better add a sleep to your script too, so that other processes get a chance in between retries.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I have tried to find a guide to "Add your script to the init process". Do you agree with the process done here(in method 3): https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

Comment: I would say yes if I was sure your system is using sysvinit, but nowadays most distributions have switched to the systemd moloch, and then you'd need solution 4 or the answer given here by Ingo.

Answer (score 1):

Start your script as service. First create a new service with:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl edit --force --full rfid-reader.service
```

Insert this statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Setting up the RFID reader
Wants=sockets.target
After=sockets.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Check the new service:

```
rpi3 ~$ systemctl status rfid-reader.service
● rfid-reader.service - Setting up the RFID reader
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rfid-reader.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Now you can enable and test your service:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl enable rfid-reader.service
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl start rfid-reader.service
```

I cannot test it because I have no RFID reader. You are alone with this. Here are some commands that may help:

```
rpi3 ~$ systemctl status rfid-reader.service
rpi3 ~$ systemctl cat rfid-reader.service
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl restart rfid-reader.service
rpi3 ~$ sudo systemctl edit --full rfid-reader.service
```

One problem is that I cannot check out for you the target after
that `/dev/ttyUSB0` is available. In the example above I use
`sockets.target`. Don't know if this already initialised `/dev/ttyUSB0`.
With

```
rpi3 ~$ systemctl
```

you will find what services and targets are active. Only look at the targets. Other candidates for `Wants=` and `After=` seem to be:

```
local-fs.target   Local File Systems
sysinit.target    System Initialization
basic.target      Basic System
```

If `sockets.target` does not work I would try other targets in this order.

Comment: When starting it as a service, would it than run on every time /dev/ttyUSB0 is available?

Comment: @DanielRobotics It is a service like any other service and can run as daemon. This simple example has by default `Type=simple`. You didn't said that you want to monitor the status of `/dev/ttyUSB0`. This is a bit more complicated. You have to modify your script to work as a daemon and maybe start it with an other `Type=`, maybe `forking` or `dbus`. Have a look at `man systemd.service` option `Type=`.

Comment: @DanielRobotics Or maybe you can use `udev` with a proper rule instead of running a service.